# Pass the route path and fence path dynamically for tracking an abject in Here API(GEO FENCING)

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, geofencing, here-api

I am using the Here Javascript API Explorer for tracking a moving map object basically used for Geo Fencing. I want to pass the route path and fence path dynamically as it is hardcoded in the code so far.

I have tried to do it with javascript array.push method i.e. to pass the value of both dynamically.but it helps me to append the array but the path for both route and fence is not loading as the page only loads once and at that time the arrays for both are empty.

```
    var routeArr = [52.53805, 13.4205, 52.53765, 13.42156, 52.53811, 13.42188,
52.53862, 13.42232, 52.53929, 13.42283, 52.53921, 13.42333];
    var routeArr2 = [52.53805, 13.4209, 52.53765, 13.42156, 52.53811, 13.42188,
52.53862, 13.42232, 52.53929, 13.42284, 52.53921, 13.42333];
                    var route = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(
                                    new nokia.maps.geo.Strip(
                                            routeArr,
                                            "values lat lng"),
                                    { color: "#7FFF00", width: 2 }
                            ),
                            imageMarker = new nokia.maps.map.Marker(
                                    route.path.get(0),
                                    {
                                        icon: "../../res/markerTruck.png",
                                        $id: "marker",
                                        anchor: {x: 21, y: 41}
                                    }
                            ),
                            circle = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(
                                    new nokia.maps.geo.Strip(
                                            routeArr2,
                                            "values lat lng"),
                                    { color: "#000000", width: 2}
                            ),

    sceneContainer = new nokia.maps.map.Container([route, imageMarker, circle]);


                    map.addListener("displayready", function () {
                        map.objects.add(sceneContainer);
                        map.zoomTo(sceneContainer.getBoundingBox());
                    })

            ;
```

I want to pass the above value of routeArr and routeArr2 dynamically.
Do we have to provide the route path and fence path before the page loads or is there a way through which we can pass the array for both dynamically ?

Comment: please add the code you have implemented for this

Answer (score 0):

The MapObject need at minimum 1 Coordinate for a Point and two Coordinates for a shape. So you can init the Objects with RouteArr1 and RouteArr2 and change it afterwards with routePolyline.set("path", STRIP); 
Where STRIP is your new strip.